# WPF: How to get the same date in two different DatePickers

Tags: wpf

I created two DatePickers (dp1 and dp2) in WPF. When I select a date on the dp1, I would like dp2 to update automatically: The date from dp1 should come to dp2. Any ideas on how I should do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer a XAML only solution over to codebehind answer.

```
<StackPanel>
    <DatePicker Name="dp1"></DatePicker>
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=dp1, Path=SelectedDate}"></DatePicker>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Was obliged to change from Winform to WPF. Thank u for your help.